# Как на vue.js + webpack сделать загрузку определённых данных позже либо при событии?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Есть сайт с множеством фотографий и текста.
Пользователь до конца может даже не пролистать, соответственно нет смысла грузить данные.
Как сделать, что б сперва загрузилось всё самое нужное, а часть данных- потом.
Второстепенные данные вконце-подгрузить вообще при скроллинге.
Вообщем вопрос больше про подгрузку вебпаком.
Например на ютубе вижу сперва макет табличный, а потом фотография из видео, что ускоряет загрузку.

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать асинхронные методы, в последнее время часто используются наряду с `ES6`.

Answer (score 0):

Загрузку данных удобно выполнять в хуке [mounted](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted). Т.е. открылась страница, вызвался хук, а уже в хуке выполняется загрузка.

Для второстепенного контента можно использовать callback [$nextTick](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick). Этот callback вызывается после того, как страница отрисовалась. Вызывается, соответственно, после хука `mounted`.

Для скроллинга можно реализовать отдельный метод, и этот метод вызывать в событие [windows.onscroll](https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll). Чтобы связать метод и событие `onscroll`, событие можно добавить,например, в хуке `mounted`.

Удачи.